# Any alternative for AVPlayerController as it is causing issues with constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using the following code and it is causing the constraint from the top for the view to get disturbed:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURLs[id] as URL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
```

also, check the behavior at [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=196C6ZqDRr4pMoH8xHka20XhgMHQ5qlIx):

Please help me fix this issue or recommend an another way to show video. I am unable to avoid this error. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Lightbox are you looking for something like this?